# Remove part of the link in a href before #anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, anchor-scroll

I have a link on my page as so:

```
<li class="jump"><a href="http://example.com/#about">About Me</a></li>
```

I'd like to use jQuery to remove the 'http://example.com/' part of any URL within a .jump class. Can you point me in the correct direction, with the simplest code possible? I want the code to remove anything before the hash, without specifying the URL (e.g. remove http://example.com/) in the jQuery code if possible.

thank you!

Comment: Just use native javascript split() function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Use `.indexOf()` and `.slice()`, or the `.split()` method. You have not put much effort into this, have you?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen what do you mean by not putting much effort?

Comment: @caustic - I think what is meant by that is that usually a user will show the attempts that were made including the relevant code. Placing this information into your question shows that you have made an effort to research the problem and have tried to solve it yourself first before posting here.

Comment: @Lix Oh. I have tried to accomplish this using PHP but didn't work out so well so I resorted to jQuery. I did a search for removing part of a URL but couldn't find much pertaining to removing before an anchor, maybe I didn't search the right terms. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

1) `.each()` to iterate over the all anchor

2) split current href on occurence of `#` and use second array element

3) concatenate the new href with `#` in front and set the new href

```
$('.jump a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href','#'+$(this).attr('href').split('#')[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I can think of would be to split the URL using the anchor character `#` as the delimiter:

```
var url = $(".jump").attr("href"); // "http://example.com/#about"
var split_url = url.split("#");
var after_hash = split_url[1];
```

Your `after_hash` variable should now contain the value: "about". You'll need to re-add the anchor character to this value if you intend to insert it back into the `href` attribute.

Since it sounds to me like you are intending to use this functionality on multiple urls, I would recommend placing this code into a function and calling when needed.

Comment: will this keep the hash intact? so it will be #about rather than just about, right?

Comment: @caustic - no. The delimiter `#` is removed when the split is executed. You'll have to add this character back to the `after_hash` variable - I've added that info into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `substring` and `lastIndexOf`.

```
$(".jump a").each(function() {    
    var $this = $(this),
        href = $this.attr("href");

    $this.attr("href", href.substring(href.indexOf("#")));        
});
```

Comment: The first `#` character in a URL is always the fragment identifier. Using `lastIndexOf` could actually find the wrong `#`, if there are more than one of them (e.g. `/abc#one#more`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it using jQuery:

```
$(".jump a").each(function() {
    var newHref = $(this).attr("href").replace("http://example.com/", "");
    $(this).attr("href", newHref);
});
```